# Ruby installation issue on Centos6

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, centos

```
# yum install libreadline5-dev libncurses5-dev

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: sg2plmirror01.shr.prod.sin2.secureserver.net
 * extras: sg2plmirror01.shr.prod.sin2.secureserver.net
 * updates: sg2plmirror01.shr.prod.sin2.secureserver.net
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 3.0 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 3.5 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
No package libreadline5-dev available.
No package libncurses5-dev available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I got above mentioned issue

Comment: what does this have to do with ruby or rake?

Comment: Those look like Debian/Ubuntu package names. CentOS uses the RedHat/Fedora package naming conventions, and development packages have names ending with "-devel". Use "yum search" or "yum provides" to look for the correct package names.

Answer (score 0):

You solution is:

```
$ sudo yum install ruby
$ sudo yum install rubygems
```